# What is an Asymphonic Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Asymphonic Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Asymphonic Words™ | Non-Asymphonic Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| CACHE | CRICKET |
| CIRCLE | CROCODILE |
| CANCER | COCK |
| GRUDGE | GANG |
| GEOGRAPHY | GEOLOGY |
| GRAPHOLOGY | GEMOLOGY |
| GAUGE | GAG |
| CROTCH | CHARACTER |

CSV version:

```
Asymphonic Words™, Non-Asymphonic Words™
CACHE, CRICKET
CIRCLE, CROCODILE
CANCER, COCK
GRUDGE, GANG
GEOGRAPHY, GEOLOGY
GRAPHOLOGY, GEMOLOGY
GAUGE, GAG
CROTCH, CHARACTER
```

Not only these but many such words exist.

Comment: I just wanted to say that "Non-Asymphonic" is a double negative and should be replaced with "Symphonic".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a Non-asymphonic word, when

> a letter appears more than once, it it pronounced the same way each time. C is a hard C, as in CROCODILE, if it appears that way at least once. GAG=hard g, hard g.

In an asymphonic word,

> a letter that appears twice (or more?) has different pronunciations. CANCER= hard c, soft c.  GAUGE=hard g, soft g.

Why you would call it *non-asymphonic* instead of *symphonic* is one of those deep mysteries.

Comment: It is probably worth noting the O's in a few of the Non- words and A's in the last one. Either it is required for all pairs, or just consonants.

Comment: The rule seems to apply to repeated consonants only, rather than all repeated letters.

Comment: @Mike Q. You are correct.  I overlooked the repeated vowels in CHARACTER, CROCODILE, and GRAPHOLOGY.

Comment: GANG probably needs more attention, since NG isn't same as G. (try to make them same, it sounds hilarious either way). +1 anyway.

Comment: @Bass Even if they don't sound quite the same, they're both a hard G sound, as opposed to being soft G sounds (Neither Jang or Ganj sound like Gang)

Comment: @R.Dye 'Symphony' means __same sound__ literally. In Asymphonic (a word that I used , which does not exist perhaps) words...the same  letter gets pronounced differently at different places, as observed by you correctly. Well done.

Comment: Similarly, non-asymptotic is the more often used antonym of asymptotic.

Comment: @Octopus is symptotic a word, though? The usage of a- comes from Greek, where perhaps sumptōtos (as opposed to asumptōtos) was a word, but I'm fairly sure that hasn't been carried to English.

Comment: @boboquack ??? google turns up lots of definitions for symptotic

Comment: @Dqwerty  It is regional.  There are certain subsets of the population in my area that pronounce it "GAng-G", much like some people pronounce the final B in LAMB and BOMB